# server unreachable from outside after IP change

Tags: routes, freebsd, netstat

We changed a deal with our ISP and now they gave us a new IP. 
Basicly there is a bridge > freebsd server > intranet
So the FREEBSD server has a static IP which was given by our ISP.

I got everything goin (apache, ssh, virtual hosts) on the inside, but it seems (as a surprise) that nothing can be reached from the OUTSIDE.

Not ssh, not apache. It justs takes a lot of time and then says either bad gateway or timed out or connection lost.

I'm afraid that I might have messed up something in the routing table, because the firewall and squid are working well (flushed the cache and all good).

So heres the routing table:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            194.126.110.153    UGS         0    42089    em1
127.0.0.1          link#6             UH          0       29    lo0
192.168.1.0/24     link#1             U           0   568386    em0
192.168.1.1        link#1             UHS         0       36    lo0
192.168.2.0/24     link#1             U           0   799372    em0
192.168.2.1        link#1             UHS         0        0    lo0
192.168.3.0/24     link#1             U           0      300    em0
192.168.3.1        link#1             UHS         0        0    lo0
192.168.4.0/24     link#1             U           0    12921    em0
192.168.4.1        link#1             UHS         0        0    lo0
194.126.110.0/24   link#4             U           0        0    em1
194.126.110.154    link#4             UHS         0      518    lo0
```

194.126.110.153 is our "bridge" or gateway, through which the IP comes. 
192.168.x.x is the intranet (em0)
em1 is the lan-card for the outside world (194.126.110.154 - new ip)

I can't remember the last route table, but I might have seen our em1 card there... can't be sure.

I've been dealing with this major problem for the whole day now and can't seem to resolve it.

Any help would be appreachiated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything working now.

When I left the server on Friday evening, frustrated and thinking of the blue Monday that will come, I was flabberghasted on the next morning to find out that BY a MIRACLE Everything was in perfect order...as if nothing had happened.

Since I didnt restart the server nor do anything afterwards, my only explanation is that our ISP might have made some mistakes on their end... Which is unlikely.